# c# dictionary return multiple min max

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, max, min

How do I get more than 1 min/max value from a dictionary if there is more than 1? I know you have to convert .ToList so you can use min/max, but when I do this it only gives me the first value it runs into that meets the requirement as being min/max.

```
class Program
{
    Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program minMaxAge = new Program();
        minMaxAge.MinMaxAge();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public Program()
    {            
        myDictionary.Add("Darius", 35);
        myDictionary.Add("Caitlin", 25);
        myDictionary.Add("Xin", 55);
        myDictionary.Add("Alistar", 25);
    }
    public void MinMaxAge()
    {
        // Have to convert to list or array in order to get min/max
        var ageRange = myDictionary.ToList(); 
        // Created easier to read Keys and Values       
        var minAge = ageRange.Min(myDictionary => myDictionary.Value);            
        var minName = myDictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == minAge).Key;

        var maxAge = ageRange.Max(myDictionary => myDictionary.Value);
        var maxName = myDictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == maxAge).Key;

        Console.WriteLine("The youngest age is {0} and that is {1}.", minAge, minName);
        Console.WriteLine("The youngest age is {0} and that is {1}.", maxAge, maxName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Get the min age as an `int` and use that to select from the dictionary. Repeat for max age.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to get all items that match the `max` value, you could use `Where` instead of `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var minAge = ageRange.Min(myDictionary => myDictionary.Value);            
var minNames = myDictionary.Where(x => x.Value == minAge).Select(p => p.Key);
```

Now you can print all names like this

```
foreach (string name in minNames) {
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

or construct a `string` with all names in it like this:

```
string allMinNames = string.Join(" ", minNames);
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try following `dictionary.Where(e => e.Value == maxAge).Select(e => e.key)`

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want with a few small changes to the LINQ instruction that you use for the names in the MinMaxAge method. Check this out:

```
public void MinMaxAge()
{
    // Have to convert to list or array in order to get min/max
    var ageRange = myDictionary.ToList();

    // Created easier to read Keys and Values       
    var minAge = ageRange.Min(myDictionary => myDictionary.Value);
    var minNames = myDictionary.Where(x => x.Value == minAge)
        .Select(x => x.Key)
        .Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);

    var maxAge = ageRange.Max(myDictionary => myDictionary.Value);
    var maxNames = myDictionary.Where(x => x.Value == maxAge)
        .Select(x => x.Key)
        .Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);

    Console.WriteLine("The youngest age is {0} and that is {1}.", minAge, minNames);
    Console.WriteLine("The youngest age is {0} and that is {1}.", maxAge, maxNames);
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for your problem is the following:

```
var max = myDictionary.Where(s => s.Value == myDictionary.Max(kvp => kvp.Value));
var min = myDictionary.Where(s => s.Value == myDictionary.Min(kvp => kvp.Value));
```

This way you won't need to convert your Dictionary to a List and also eliminate the extra step of saving the max and min age in own variables from the other posted solution.

Comment: This is a very expensive solution, the aggragate will be called once per item in the collection giving you n^2 time complexity